# How to prevent .json requests with Turn.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using turn.js on my sales page here (http://www.breakintobartending.com/highball/) and I'd like to know how to prevent the flipbook from making .json file requests for each page. I don't have any clickable items anywhere in the book, but the code is still making requests for these .json files (which slows down the load time a bit).

What bit of code do I remove (or add?) to prevent the page from requesting these files.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your file "Magazine.js", you have, at line 76 the following code

```
function loadRegions(page, element) {
  $.getJSON(grerda_basePath+'pages/'+page+'-regions.json').
  done(function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, region) {
       addRegion(region, element);
     });
  });
}
```

I think you can delete or comment it to see what it does.

It took me something like 30seconds to find this ajax call. To find it, I just open firefox + firebug, and searched for the string ".json" inside your code.

You can add breakpoints, and look into the console to check what you've done

Comment: Yes, I already tried this method and when I remove those exact lines of code, it breaks the flipbook and the book doesn't show up at all.

Comment: OK, upon trying the method outlined by patxy, I realized that another line in Magazine.js references "loadRegions," and deleting "loadRegions" was messing up the script. I just ended up deleting that line (which was at around line 53 or so) and everything worked fine.

Comment: It broke because, after having removed the lines I pointed out, javascript was trying to find an undefined function. Normally, you should now delete those lines without having problems. (that way, you will avoid death code, and having it easier for next debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can just remove any "x-regions.json" files from the "pages" subfolder.  (Where x is a page number ...)  This of course assumes that the "magazine.js" is smart and caches this data so on following page interactions it doesn't re-request something that is not there.  For a small Magazine with few pages, this should not matter as the requests amounts would be trivial.

Commenting out the call to "loadRegions" in "magazine.js" is a great option.